# Setting a session variable before AutoPostBack fires in an asp:Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, aspbutton

How would I go about setting a session variable from the click of an ASP:Button before an AutoPostBack event fires.

Here is what I have right now, but I'm not exactly sure I'm doing this right:

```
 <asp:Button ID="CommitBTN" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/MMR_Home.aspx" 
 onclick="CommitBTN_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true" 
 OnClientClick='<% string temp1 = "true"; Session["ClickedFlag"] = temp1; %>' Text="Commit Changes to Database" />
```

Would this be the correct way of performing this action or am I going at it completely wrong?

EDIT:

Changed my button tag to this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="CommitBTN" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/MMR_Home.aspx" 
 onclick="CommitBTN_Click" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('<%= Hidden.ClientID
  %>').value='1'" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Commit Changes to Database" />
```

I receive this as my error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Comment: Do you need more help for this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

**Inside aspx file:**

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="CommitBTN" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="CommitBTN_Click" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('HiddenField').value='Ram'"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" />
</form>
```

**Or**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setMyHiddenField(myValue) {
        document.getElementById('HiddenField').value = myValue;
}
</script>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="CommitBTN" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="CommitBTN_Click" OnClientClick="setMyHiddenField('Ram')"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" />
```

==================================================================

**Inside aspx.cs file**

```
protected void CommitBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ClickedFlag"] = HiddenField.Value;
        Response.Write(Session["ClickedFlag"]);
    }
```

It is easy to replase "Ram" with your value. ;)

you can change Ram to temp1 easy:

**setMyHiddenField('temp1')**

Or you can call this function on your another control events befor CommitBTN pressed

Comment: Both of these answers I will try.  I would have never though to use a hidden field.  I will let you guys know how it goes.

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Comment: I guess I really don't need to set a session variable, I just need to know that the asp:button was clicked.  The previous answers to this question are close.  All I want to be able to do in the Page_Load is say "if (button.clicked == true) then set a flag.

Comment: I added a new js function to my codes.use it any where of your page that you want (in this case remove OnClientClick event).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a `Hidden Field` control.
2. Update the  `Hidden Field` to 1 on Button `Client` Click.
3. Update the `Session Value` in the `Page Load' event. The Value will be 1 then update the Session variable and set the`Hidden Field`value to 0 underneath the`Session Variable` Update.
4. Reason for the Usage of `Page Load` event is that on clicking the `Button` as per the `page life cycle` the page events like PreInit, Init, InitComplete, PreLoad, Load executes before the `execution` of `Button` Control.

`Page events` execution takes place like below..

> 1. Preinit
> 2. Init
> 3. InitComplete
> 4. PreLoad
> 5. Load
> 6. Control Event
> 7. Load Complete
> 8. Pre Render

Hope this will help you...